# Mean stack Schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using MEAN stack where I have `users` which can build `charts`.

```
where `user, chart` = mongoose schemas
```

My questions is how can I link the charts created by users with the user itself so I can display the past created charts on the admin page?

```
var ChartSchema = new Schema({
   name: [String],
   type: [String],
   data: [Array]
});

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  email: { type: String, lowercase: true },
  role: {
    type: String,
    default: 'user'
  },
  hashedPassword: String,
  provider: String,
  salt: String,
  twitter: {},
  google: {}
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By adding an attribute in the ChartSchema or an Array of Chart in the UserSchema. 
Add and _id field on both Schema.

```
ChartSchema = new Schema({
// ...
   _creator: { type: Number, ref: 'User' },
});
```

Or

```
UserSchema = new Schema({
// ... 
   chartsCreated: [{ type: Number, ref: 'Chart' }]
});
```

Assuming that the ChartSchema is register as `Chart` and the UserSchema as `User`.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for confusion!

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe you can add an attribute named created in the ChartSchema so that you can display somebody's charts by published time like this:

```
var ChartSchema = new Schema({
    created: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now
    },
    user: {
      type: Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    }
});

mongoose.model('Charts', ChartSchema);
```

And

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
//    ...
    charts: [{
      type: Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Charts'
    }]
});

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

In the controller file, for example:

```
Charts.find().sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function (err, charts) {
//    ...
});
```

To learn more details, you can see the [MEAN Stack Docs](http://meanjs.org/docs/0.3.x/) and [Mongoose Docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html)

Answer (score 0):

In your user schema add a new field chartData and you need not change your Chart Schema.

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
      name: String,
      email: { type: String, lowercase: true },
      role: {
        type: String,
        default: 'user'
      },
      hashedPassword: String,
      provider: String,
      salt: String,
      twitter: {},
      google: {},
      chartData : [ChartSchema]
    });
```

and also export your schema

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)